# TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string

```
import json
import requests

url = 'http://developer.usa.gov/1usagov.json'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

for line in r.iter_lines():
    if line:
        print (json.loads(line))
```

Gives this error:

```
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

While viewing through the browser i do see that the response is a Json but request library says its a bytes like object why so ?

Comment: Generally when things are passed around the network, they're in the form of bytes

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you use Python 3.x, you should pass `str` object to [`json.loads`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).

Replace following line:

```
print(json.loads(line))
```

with:

```
print(json.loads(line.decode()))
```

UPDATE: The behavior changed in Python 3.6. The argument can now be of type bytes or bytearray. The input encoding should be UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32.

Comment: @nehemiah I'd rather get an exception than have a bug in my code.

Comment: No, json loads expects a string, which means it would coerce(try to convert) the incoming object into string, which is what happens in p2 and it's very pythonic. Why do you think this will lead to a bug?

Comment: @nehemiah, Behavior changed in Python 3.6: Changed in version 3.6: s can now be of type bytes or bytearray. The input encoding should be UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32.
(https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)
This question is tagged python-3.x, so I answered based on Python 3.x behavior (prior to Python 3.6).